# Meaning of 殺しやすかい

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, reading-comprehension

This is from the first Conan manga. Some mobsters have just knocked out Conan, and one of them says:

> こいつ、[殺]{バラ}しやすかい⁉︎

What is going on here grammatically? Is it し易い with the い dropped, so it means "Shouldn't it be easy to kill this guy? / Can't we just kill him?"?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, 〜ます→〜やす is what is going on?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Super, thanks :)